# Change text of UIAlertView when recording a video with UIImagePickerController and reaching the videoMaximumDuration

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'd want to know how to change to text of the `UIAlertView` appearing when I record a video with a `UIImagePickerController` and I reach the videoMaximumDuration.
If it is not possible to change the text of that `UIAlertView`, is it at least possible to display it in another language ?

Edit : the default text is "The maximum length for this video has been reached" with title "Video Recording Stopped".

Thank you,
aimak

Comment: Hi, I am also having the same situation. Is it possible to skip this alertView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of the alert is localized to the current locale settings of the device, and unless you want to walk the view hierarchy looking for the UIAlertView and set its `message` property (which is fragile and would need to be tested across all versions of iOS you're deploying to), you'll probably need to create a fully custom UI on top of a capture session. The picker controller delegate protocol doesn't have callbacks for when recording stops and starts, so there isn't a good way to control it manually and supply your own alert without going much lower-level in AVFoundation.

Comment: Okay I could have guessed that it would use the current locale settings of the device. The thing is, I set my devices in French but the alert was still displayed in English.
What I did not know was that I could force the localization in the xib file. It solved my problem.
Thank you for the clarification, though !