# "Video recording stopped" system msg - Is there a way to change it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app i'm using `videoMaximumDuration = 15`. After 15 seconds I'm getting this alert msg:

> **Video recording stopped**
>
> The maximum length for this video has been reached.

The msg will be in english regardless of the device language.

Is there any way to remove that msg or change the text \ language to something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The text of the alert is localized to the current locale settings of the device, and unless you want to walk the view hierarchy looking for the UIAlertView and set its `message` property (which is fragile and would need to be tested across all versions of iOS you're deploying to), you'll probably need to create a fully custom UI on top of a capture session. The picker controller delegate protocol doesn't have callbacks for when recording stops and starts, so there isn't a good way to control it manually and supply your own alert without going much lower-level in AVFoundation.

[warrenm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588672/change-text-of-uialertview-when-recording-a-video-with-uiimagepickercontroller-a)