# How to customize UIAlert Message after reach videoMaxiumDuration property on UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

After set the videoMaximumDuration property, how to customize the UIAlert message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can't do this in UIImagePickerController.
From Documentation:

> To perform fully-customized image or movie capture, instead use the AV
>   Foundation framework as described in [Media Capture and Access to
>   Camera](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom UI for that I have found this answer on  [[Change text of UIAlertView when recording a video with UIImagePickerController and reaching the videoMaximumDuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588672/change-text-of-uialertview-when-recording-a-video-with-uiimagepickercontroller-a][1])