# How to change custom iOS video recording messages?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am recording video in iOS using UIImagePickerController.I have added maximum 15 second video recording in iOS.i have used below code for that.

```
 if cameraOptions == .Video {
    imagePicker.videoQuality = .typeHigh
    imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 15
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
    }
```

[image]

I want to change below things

1. Change Alert text in the UIAlertView or can i remove this alert
2. VIDEO_TOO_LONG_TITLE text.Can i remove this message label.

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588672/change-text-of-uialertview-when-recording-a-video-with-uiimagepickercontroller-a

Comment: Plus what I suggest you to do is handle it your self. When the video reaches a certain limit pop a alertview and handle video recording yourself.  And if you dont want to edit it, setting imagePicker.allowsEditing = false will remove the VIDEO_TOO_LONG_TITLE message.

Comment: how would i know that video recording has reached to certain limit ?

Comment: since it UIImagePickerController does not have any delegate method to handle this. You could use timer which initiates when the video starts, pauses when pauses and once it reach the limit prompt your own message.

Comment: I can't do this.Because i have no way to know when video recording started & when video recording stopped.